# Azure DevOps pipeline enter variable value from UI

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want user to enter value of the variable before click on Run pipeline button

I have empty variable in `pipeline.yml`:

```
- name: projectName
  value:
```

But UI doesn't show it:

[image]

How should I define var for user's input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline):

> You can choose which variables are allowed to be set at queue time,
>   and which are fixed by the pipeline author. If a variable appears in
>   the variables block of a YAML file, it's fixed and can't be overridden
>   at queue time. To allow a variable to be set at queue time, make sure
>   it doesn't appear in the variables block of a pipeline or job. You can
>   set a default value in the editor, and that value can be overridden by
>   the person queuing the pipeline.

So, you should remove it from the YAML and define in via the UI.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `runtime parameters` instead of using variables.